# Any function like uci_load() but load config file not under /etc/config?

Tags: openwrt, uci

Any uci function like uci_load() but load config file not under /etc/config?
Can we specify directory not in /etc/config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this in C then it looks like you could create a new `uci_context` struct with the path specified in `confdir`.

Based on looking at: https://lxr.openwrt.org/source/uci/uci.h#L397

Comment: Thanks for help! It seems I can use uci_set_confdir() to change it.